# ASP.net core 2. 0 get error when use transaction scope : The requested operation cannot be completed because the connection has been broken

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, transactionscope, sqltransaction

I have created an API to add multiple items. I use transaction scope because I don't have to insert all items if found a problem in any item. so I have used TransactionScope so doing dispose of the transaction if found any validation failed in an item.
 I use a loop of 100 items to avoid database time out, but in the loop, I got error like

"The requested operation cannot be completed because the connection has been broken".

please let me know any solution tom fulfill my requirements

I send XML to the database of each 100 items in a loop. 
code is a per below

```
using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
{
        try
        {
          for (int i = 0; i < objPricebook.ItembookMasterObject.Length; i = i + 100)
          {
             List<ItembookMasterObject> items = objPricebook.ItembookMasterObject.Skip(i).Take(100).ToList();
             string ItemXML = CreateXML(items); // CreateXML is function i have created to convert data in to XML
             if (ItemXML != "")
                 {
                   DS = obj.AddItemBook(ItemXML, objGuid.ToString());
                    if (DS.Tables.Count > 0)
                      {
                        if (DS.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)// this means any validation is failed. 
                          {
                            transactionScope.Dispose();
                            var id = obj.AddPriceBookLogError(DS.Tables[0]);
                             return Json(new { status = "Failed", message = "There is some problem with Item json });
                           }
                        }
                   }
            }



       }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
      transactionScope.Dispose();
      return Json(new { message = "Item Json has some invalid imput", exceptionMessage = ex.Message, errorCode = "009" });
      }

     transactionScope.Complete();
     transactionScope.Dispose();
     return Json(new { status = "Success", message = "Price book is successfully added" });
}
```

Comment: remove `transactionScope.Dispose();` in for loop..better write in `finally` block only once and remove from all places. you are already using `using` so ne need to dispose explicitly

Comment: @viveknuna I have to dispose of the transaction if the count is greater then zero because it indicates validation error which I return from the database. so no need to loop again if found any error. problem is when it goes to loop for second time , it throws error as i mentioned

Comment: then simply return from there, butdont use dispose

Comment: @viveknuna  okay thanks for the suggestion but it will not solve my problem because that case I don't have faced.  do u have any idea to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your current implementation is overkill. `using` blocks always call `Dispose()` when execution leaves the block, regardless of how that happens. As such, you don't need to call `Dispose()` directly.

```
using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
{
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < objPricebook.ItembookMasterObject.Length; i = i + 100)
        {
            List<ItembookMasterObject> items = objPricebook.ItembookMasterObject.Skip(i).Take(100).ToList();
            string ItemXML = CreateXML(items); // CreateXML is function i have created to convert data in to XML
            if (ItemXML != "")
            {
                DS = obj.AddItemBook(ItemXML, objGuid.ToString());
                if (DS.Tables.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (DS.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)// this means any validation is failed. 
                    {
                        var id = obj.AddPriceBookLogError(DS.Tables[0]);
                        return Json(new { status = "Failed", message = "There is some problem with Item json" });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new { message = "Item Json has some invalid imput", exceptionMessage = ex.Message, errorCode = "009" });
    }

    transactionScope.Complete();
    return Json(new { status = "Success", message = "Price book is successfully added" });
}
```